# How to display all images "Uploaded By" an author

Tags: media, author

I have multiple users, that have the ability to upload media. When I look at the media library it shows the file information, and included at the bottom is an "Uploaded By 'username'"

How can I use this username to loop through the media library and display all images from a user?

Here's a picture of the information with the media.

[image: media name]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it via WP_Query loop:

```
$args = array(
   'author'      => $author_id, // Replace with author id
   'post_status' => 'any',
   'post_type'   => 'attachment'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

More info how to use WP_Query: [Codex WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)